Touchpad suddenly stopped working and is no longer being detected
A series of errors popped up in my dmesg such as follows,
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.675678] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.695915] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.716175] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.736364] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.756532] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.776700] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.796882] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.817029] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.837152] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.857409] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.877620] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.897798] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.917982] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.938189] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.958382] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.978602] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready
Jun 19 01:45:20 universe kernel: [32041.998808] i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: timeout waiting for bus ready

Following these errors, my touchpad stopped working but was nonetheless being detected in xinput list. After I googled around for this error, it seemed that indeed this error has an association with breaking the touchpad but that a suspend or a reboot seems to fix the issue. I did the reboot but now, not only is my touchpad not being detected anymore but it ofcourse isn't working either.
Here is my xinput list:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

sudo rmmod psmouse gives,
rmmod: ERROR: Module psmouse is not currently loaded

/proc/bus/input/devices' output is this now:
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1a/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=174f Product=2459 Version=0008
N: Name="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c077 Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech USB Optical Mouse" [this is my USB mouse]
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/0003:046D:C077.0002/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10

I am using ThinkPad 15 G2.
How can I fix this issue?

Providing more details about your software stack could be helpful; you've tagged Xubuntu, but haven't said what release (ie. age of stack) and if a LTS release which kernel stack you're using (LTS releases have choice; with Xubuntu the default is set by install media & we currently don't know your release, let alone which media you used to install it)
